# I want to open and run a VBA macro without showing the new Excel window open

Tags: vba, excel

I have built a macro that opens runs a macro in the opened Excel file then closes. Can I make it so when the new window opens it does not show (hidden)?
If I can how do I add it to the code below?

```
Sub Open_Fill_Close()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
invoiceNo = Range("A1")

Set myData = Workbooks.Open("HD:Users:UserT:Desktop:QR.xlsm")
Worksheets("QR Code").Select
Worksheets("QR Code").Range("Y39").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("QR Code").Range("Y39").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("QR Code").Range("Y39")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0) = invoiceNo

End With

Application.Run "QR.xlsm!ExportCellsAsPicture"

Workbooks("QR.xlsm").Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you storing the macro in another workbook? I do not think you can do what you want to do. However if you stored it as an custom ribbon or something you could achieve this, but it would get a lot more complicated

Comment: select an answer to say if this can be closed. Keep SO clean, and let us not inflate unanswered question count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the actions of the macro from the screen, add 
`Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the beginning of your code. Set it back to `True` at the end.

Comment: Where about exactly do I put that in my code? Thanks!

Comment: Generally, at the very beginning and very end of your code. ie: `Sub Foo()` Then `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new application instance. opening sheets in the current session of Excel will make them visible

```
Dim xlApp as New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = False 'Visible is False by default, so this isn't necessary
Dim myData As Excel.Workbook
Set myData = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("HD:Users:UserT:Desktop:QR.xlsm")
myData.Worksheets("QR Code").Select
myData.Worksheets("QR Code").Range("Y39").Select
RowCount = myData.Worksheets("QR Code").Range("Y39").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With myData.Worksheets("QR Code").Range("Y39")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0) = invoiceNo

End With

Application.Run "QR.xlsm!ExportCellsAsPicture"

Workbooks("QR.xlsm").Close False

wrkBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit
```